# Invalid index error and the TypeError and self checking indexing error

Tags: python

can anyone help me in clearing this error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaYI4.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G29SC.png)
i am unable to understand what the error is. and i could not find any solution online.
as i am not having any knowledge about the self-checking indexing error and all those errors displayed on the image.

i tried to run the code on jupyter and visual studio but ended up getting the same error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode [how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

I think your `DataFrame` `data` doesn't have a column with name `'text'` so you get an `KeyError`, there is a short article about this [error](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fix-keyerror-in-pandas/). Maybe you mixed up table names or deleted this column before